# Why when I use GroupBy() in my LINQ to Entities query, the navigation property in the result is null?

Tags: c#, dictionary, group-by, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first

**Edited:**

I'm developing an application with EF code first, I have a method that return a `Dictionary<int,T>`:

```
public Dictionary<int, DocumentStationHistory> GetLastDocumentStationHistoryListOfDocuments(string criteria)
{
        Dictionary<int, DocumentStationHistory> result = new Dictionary<int, DocumentStationHistory>();
        using (IUnitOfWork uow = new MyContext())
        {
            DocumentStationHistoryRepository repository = new DocumentStationHistoryRepository(uow);
            result = repository.All().
                Include(x => x.DocumentStation).
                Where(criteria,new object[]{}).
                OrderBy(d=>d.DocumentId).
                OrderBy(d=>d.DocumentStationHistoryId).
                GroupBy(g => (int)g.DocumentId).
                ToDictionary(g => (int)g.Key, g => g.LastOrDefault());
            return result;
        }
}
```

Also it's the relation between my entities:

[image]

But when this method runs, the included property(`DocumentStation`) in the result is `null`. where is my mistake?

**Updated:**

**I tested that if I remove the `.GroupBy()`, it keeps the navigation property!**
So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need .All()

Comment: @SamLeach: I need .All() because i want to filter all records with an criteria

Comment: It will filter all records by default.

Comment: It will filter all DocumentStationHistory records with my criteria, and i want this. my returned records are ok, but navigation properties are null.

Comment: could you also show the configuration for the relationship of DocumentStationHistory and AppUser

Comment: I'm not really sure how that query will work at all... All() has no overload with 0 arguments and Where does not have an overload for (string, ?). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue. I solved it by doing a .ToList() before the group by. So it would be:

```
result = repository.All().
         Include(x => x.DocumentStation).
         Where(criteria,new object[]{}).
         OrderBy(d=>d.DocumentId).
         OrderBy(d=>d.DocumentStationHistoryId).
         ToList().
         GroupBy(g => (int)g.DocumentId).
         ToDictionary(g => (int)g.Key, g => g.LastOrDefault());
```

Comment: But this cause, first load all data from `Database` and then `Group` them, and this impact the performance.

Comment: You should use `.AsEnumerable` instead of `.ToList`.  It streams the preceding results instead of stuffing a list full of data.